# python: where is a true built-in file object required?

Tags: python, api, file, interface, standard-library

From the python docs on `urllib.urlopen()`, talking about the file-like object the function returns on success:

> (It is not a built-in file object, however, so it can’t be used at those few places where a true built-in file object is required.)

What are those few places where a true built-in file object is required?

NB: This is purely out of curiosity... no practical problem to be solved here.

Comment: I guess Python is violating it's own duct typing rules? >=D

Comment: "duct typing"?  The usual spelling is "duck typing".

Comment: If you want to see us violate duck-typing, try using a string-like type that doesn't inherit from `str` (or `unicode` in 2.x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answers have noted, there isn't really anywhere that specifically needs a `file` object, but there are interfaces that need *real* OS level file descriptors, which file-like objects like `StringIO` can't provide.

The `os` module has several methods that operate directly on file descriptors, as do the `select` and `mmap` modules. Some higher level modules rely on those under the hood, so may exhibit some limitations when working with file-like objects that don't support the `fileno()` method.

I'm not aware of any consistent documentation of these limitations, though (aside from the obvious one of APIs that accept numeric file descriptors rather than objects). It's more a matter of "try it and see if it works". If things don't work, then this is something to keep in the back of your mind to check as a possible culprit (especially if phrases like `"no attribute named 'fileno'"` or `"invalid file descriptor"` appear in any relevant error messages).

Comment: The fun doesn't stop: Not all file-like objects (or even "files" -- think FIFO/named pipe) will support seeking, for example.

Comment: Yup. I think that's the main reason nobody has even tried to comprehensively document just what can be used where - exactly which parts of the interface you need depends heavily on what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 2):

Things in the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module need a file object with a [`fileno`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.fileno) callable attribute for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`, which [only files with a file descriptor (real files) should implement](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.fileno). [`isatty()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.isatty) should also be implemented only in real files, but I don't know where it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

For example, f.fileno() doesn't necessarily return a true OS-level file descriptor that you could use with os.read().

Comment: But it should. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.fileno): "Note File-like objects which do not have a real file descriptor should not provide this method!"